# Square sum of $L^2$ orthonormal basis diverges almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{e_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be any orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$, prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|e_n(x)|^2$ diverges almost everywhere.

Comment: Certainly not true for $\mathbb N$ with counting measure.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks! I delete the last sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of $\sum |f_n (x)|https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249464

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right